# python job queue library for desktop

Tags: python

I want to develop a PyQt contacts list desktop application and i wanted some jobs to be performed from time to time when some event happens.For instance,i want when i hit the contact button,a job of sending an emial is added to the queue and is done after 5 minutes.

I have seen some job queuing solutions and they require redis or some other kind of a broker.I want my app to be simple and so bundling servers such as redis is not something i would like.

Is there a simple job queue that i can use to perform the simple jobs i plan on having in my app without requiring huge service brokers?.

Comment: so.. why dont you spawn a thread, make it sleep for 5 min and then send the mail?

Comment: I cannot honestly say i thought about that possibility. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that comes to my mind is [Quartz framework](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) - it's a scheduler, originates in Java (I think). So I looked for it and found another question here at stackoverflow: [An enterprise scheduler for python (like quartz)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727138/an-enterprise-scheduler-for-python-like-quartz), and it looks like a good match.

Answer (score 2):

For schedule task,

- for *nux , use [crontab](http://kvz.io/blog/2007/07/29/schedule-tasks-on-linux-using-crontab/)
- for win, use
  [windows schedule task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  or  use simply "at" command

For message queue,

- for win, you can use message queue [windows message queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [pika (rabbitmq client)](https://github.com/pika/pika), [rabbitmq server](http://www.rabbitmq.com)
- [pymq](https://code.google.com/p/pymq/)
- [redis server](http://redis.io/), [redis py client](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py) (redis provide simple queue server, which support subscribe and publish)